# Access elements inside numpy.where index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm a beginner to the Python world and hope someone can answer my question. I haven an array and need to access certain indices of elements as below

```
x = np.random.rand(10)

x
array([ 0.56807058,  0.8404783 ,  0.86835717,  0.76030882,  0.40242679,
        0.22941009,  0.56842643,  0.94541468,  0.92813747,  0.95980955])

indx = np.where(x < 0.5)

indx
(array([4, 5], dtype=int64),)
```

However, when I try to access first element with `indx[0]` it returns `array([4, 5], dtype=int64)`. What I want to do is access elements 4 and 5 inside `indx`. Thank you for looking into my question and any support.

Comment: if `indx[0]` gets `array([4, 5]`, what do you think will get 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.where` returns a `tuple` of indices. In this case the tuple contains only one array of indices. This consistent with how `where` handles multi-dimensional arrays. It returns a tuple containing multiple arrays which together define the indices of the non-zero elements.

To access `4` from `indx` you would do: `indx[0][0]`. The first `[0]` selects the first element of the `indx` tuple, which is `array([4, 5], dtype=int64)` and the second accesses an element of this array.